# Splitting list into multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I have generated a list of size 6 "by 1". But I would like to split the list into 3 "columns" so that the size should be 2 "by 3". How can I do this?

For example:

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3] # -> [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
```

Comment: How should the elements be distributed through each of the three columns?

Comment: It is rather difficult to understand the actual problem here.

Comment: What about a case when list length is not divisible by 3, e.g, 21002 ?

Comment: I want to start new column when the size of last row is 7000..elements are sequencential, first 7000 elements should come in first come and so on

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your current list is called `flat`:

```
col_width = len(flat) // 3
nested = [flat[i:i+col_width] for i in range(0, len(flat), col_width)]
```